# XSLT namespace axis seems not to work

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:my="my_namespace">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/namespace::my"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

ant it always returns an empty string.

What is wrong with `namespace::*`?

**Update:** sample xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo/>
```

Comment: What is `xmlna:my="my_namespace"`? I am guessing it is supposed to be: `xmlns:my="my_namespace"`. Can you also post a sample of the XML you expect to get this output from?

Comment: @Sawa: The input document actually is not relevant here as it is not used by your XSLT. What processor are you using and what is the expected *output*?

Comment: I'm using libxslt via PHP with SimpleXML. As I know for such way of processing I don't need `<?xml-stylesheet?>` declaration for successful transformation. I want to get value of @xmlns:my.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MSXSL (3 and 4), Altova, Saxon, Oracle and XQSharp, it outputs:

```
my_namespace
```

If this is not the output for your processor, then maybe it doesn't handle `namespace` axis.

Answer (score 0):

Savva, I ran your stylesheet with xsltproc (under oXygen), and it output `my_namespace` as desired.

xsltproc is just a command-line frontend to libxslt. So (unless they changed something in recent versions), you and I should be getting the same results.

Why don't you **show us your PHP** / SimpleXML code - maybe the problem is in how you're accessing the result.